# AJAX form submission in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, django, ajax

I keep receiving 'Not Ajax' as a response during my form submission. I have to be missing something small but I cannot see it...

```
class VideoLikeView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            message = 'Ajax'
        else:
            message = 'Not Ajax'
        return HttpResponse(message)
```

The AJAX code looks like this:

```
$(function () {
  $("#like-form").submit(function (event) {
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr('action'),
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            data: {'pk': $(this).attr('value')},
            success: function(response) {
                alert('Video liked');
          },
          error: function(rs, e) {
                 alert(rs.responseText);
          }
        }
    });
});
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<form id="like-form" action="{% url 'video-like' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="like"
           type="hidden"
           value="{{ video.id }}">
    <button type="submit">
        <span class="video-options ml-auto fas fa-heart fa-2x m-2"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

One question to add to this; how can I use an `<input>` in my form without using a `<button>`? I would like to use fontawesome icons but it seems I have to use a button to get the form to submit.

Comment: Try to add header `X-Requested-With`: `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you check that header exists in the request headers?

Comment: When I `print(request.headers)` I get `{' 'Cookie': 'csrftoken=ciZMNklwXp7yQuSSiyzk8Zg3tBbKq0i0IhWKlZjd9Gfeht3i4CpKm0Jw1wbjkqnw; '}` inside it

Comment: Ok, I got it to work after digging around for ~2 hours since the beginning of this. I will post the answer but I don't understand *why* so maybe you could help me understand...

Answer (score 0):

I found one answer on the internet that seems to work but I don't understand what the issue was. Seems like some type of serialization needed (?)... Anyways, here is what worked:

```
var frm = $('#like-form');

frm.submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');

        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Would love to hear from people why this works and not the previous..

Answer (score 0):

try change your btn type button and add ID for event click :
since putting the submit button goes directly to view.py without going through AJAX

```
<form id="like-form" action="{% url 'video-like' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="like"
       type="hidden"
       value="{{ video.id }}" id="id_pk">
<button type="button" id="id_btn">
    <span class="video-options ml-auto fas fa-heart fa-2x m-2"></span>
</button>
```

in your script

```
$("#id_btn").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
        url:window.location.origin + 'your url'
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'pk':$(#id_pk).val(), 'accion':'guardar'},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');

        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    });
});
```

and your view.py

```
def post(self, request):
    if 'guardar' in request.POST['accion']:
       print("")
```